# How to use the DS2482 kernel module

Tags: kernel, driver

I want to use the ds2482 kernel module/driver but I'm struggling to find an example to start with. I've googled many searches but I swamped with git trees and source trees.

I've loaded it OK and it shows with lsmod.

What I'm looking for is some c code and a header file. The header file in the kernel source is a blank file so I'm really at a loss at the moment.

You may ask why not use the ow system, the reason is that I want to control the timing of the readings.

So I any one could point me in the right direction I'd be really happy.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the module you can just load it up with modprobe

```
$ sudo modprobe ds2482
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use these functions which are shown in [this document](http://kerneldox.com/kdox-linux/d9/db4/ds2482_8c.html)

If you want to see kernel code in your system you have to install/download kernel source package.

You should check this [Kernel Space - User Space Interfaces](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html) document for kernel space - user space interactions.

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere. I have the code on my system and I have successfully been able to cross compile it on a PC.The link you gave me is a good description of the module itself. The only header file ds2482.h I have found in the linux source is an empty file. Are there any examples/tutorials of using a linux module from a c application any where