# DS18B20 not detected on Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, ds18b20, breadboard

In ls /sys/bus/w1/devices/ I only have w1_bus_master1

I have added w1-gpio and w1-therm in /etc/modules

I have also added dtoverlay=w1-gpio in /boot/config.txt

I am not sure what is wrong. The RP 4 doesn’t detect the device

Here are photos of my gpio readall and the wiring: https://imgur.com/a/qu5o4h0

Does anyone have any advice or solutions? Thanks :)

If it helps, I’m following the tutorial on making a weather station from the raspberry pi website

Comment: `Here are photos of my gpio readall and the wiring:` not very useful ... wiring diagram (hint: schematic) would be better

Comment: this might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111412/rpi3b-python-ds2482-i2c-to-1-wire-bridge-connecting-10-ds18b20-temperature-sen/119865#119865